# Test for true against boolean or notnull / empty against string

Tags: java

In order to get the names of the Sections with True or NotNull/NotEmpty values I am creating a Map from the following Java object then iterating over it.

```
public class Assessment {

private Boolean section1Checkbox1;
private Boolean section1Checkbox2;
private Boolean section1Comments;

private Boolean section2Checkbox1;
private Boolean section2Checkbox2;
private Boolean section2Comments;

more sections.....
```

I have converted the object to a Map which I then iterate over:

```
    Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(needsAssessment, Map.class);

    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if (pair.getValue()==true||NotNull) {
            // Get Section Name
            String[] sectionName = pair.getKey().toString().split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
            System.out.println(sectionName[0]);
        }
    }
```

There is a error with the pair.getValue() test:

[image]

> Is there a way to test for true (if boolean) and NotNull or Empty (if
>   string) in one statement?
>   (Or a better approach?)

Comment: Is it possible for your map to be a `Map<String, Boolean>`?

Comment: first of all, don't use raw types. secondly use `instanceOf` for checking if it's `Boolean` or `String` and if it is, *cast* it using `(String) pair.getValue()` or `(Boolean) pair.getValue()`

Comment: @Lino would you be able to provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

This code works thanks @Lino :

```
Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(assessment, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);

Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if (pair.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
        Boolean currentCheckbox = (Boolean) pair.getValue();
        // Get Section/Subject Name
        System.out.println(pair.getKey());
        if (currentCheckbox) {
            String[] sectionName = pair.getKey().toString().split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
            System.out.println(sectionName[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Iterators directly should be avoided when possible, because they add unnecessary complexity. The less error prone alternatives are [for-each loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (Java 5 - 7) and [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) (Java 8 +)

Comment: Answer OP, please excuse this comment;
@NiklasMertsch just a quick comment regarding your edit proposal. I understand your proposal but I think it's better to make that a comment to this answer instead of an edit. Improving source code is a little more complicated than simply improving the text, [as discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2431281)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code, which shows the more idiomatic Java 8+ way of using lambdas and streams for collection filtering and transforming:

```
Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(assessment, Map.class);
map.entrySet()
   // stream all entries
   .stream() 
   // filter by value being TRUE (this is null safe)
   .filter((e) -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue())) 
   // transform entry to key split by regex
   .map(e -> e.getKey().split("(?=\\p{Upper})"))
   // transform to first array item
   .map(a -> a[0])
   // print
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```